# how to use min in nested dict?

Tags: python, min

if I have:

```
a = {
    (1,1): {'prev': '.', 'cur': '.', 'possible': ['2', '7', '8', '9']},
    (2,2): {'prev': '.', 'cur': '.', 'possible': ['1', '3', '8']},
    (3,3): {'prev': '.', 'cur': '.', 'possible': ['2', '7', '8', '9', '8']}
}
```

And I want to get the key that has shortest length of `'possible'`.

I wrote:

```
b = min(a, key=lambda x: len(a[x]['possible']))
```

It actually works.
Is there another way I can write? I was trying to see if I can use `get()` in `dict` methods.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your current way? To use `get()` you can just do `len(a.get(x).get('possible'))` instead.

Comment: probably, you should, add to the get the default value of zero, to avoid the case when `possible` is not included in the dict.
like `b = min(a, key=lambda x: len(a[x].get('possible', []))`
In case that case makes sense.

Comment: @Idlehands  nothing, I was just trying to understand how to use get() in a nested way....just for fun, and somehow I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: @ekiim  Thanks. A good suggestions, but not needed here, as I initialized the dict with empty list for possible.

Comment: This is a use case where it would be nice to have a composition operator for functions. `min(a, key=len*itemgetter("possible")*a.get)` (where `f1 * f2 == lambda x: f1(f2(x))`). Or `key=a.get >> itemgetter("possible") >> len` if you more comfortably pushing values in the other directly; `f1 >> f2 == lambda x: f2(f1(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you could go:

```
b = min(a, key=lambda x: len(a.get(x).get('possible')))
```

But your solution is good itself.

Comment: thanks. Trying to understand this `get()` here, somehow I am always confused by it.

Comment: The difference between dict[key] and get(key) is that if the key doesn't exists, get() returns None while dict[key] raises and error. You are welcome and happy coding!